# How to add a progress bar when data is loading from Firebase real-time database?

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-progressbar

I want to add a progress bar when data is loading from the Firebase real-time database. I don't have any idea of adding a progress bar when data is loading. I have provided the activity coding below. Can anyone help me to do this?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanking you.......................

```
package com.example.bhaskargogoi.questionpaper;

        import ...

        public class View_PDF_Files extends AppCompatActivity {

            ListView myPDFListView;
            DatabaseReference databaseReference;
            List<uploadPDF> uploadPDFS;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_view__pdf__files);

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("View Question Papers");
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                myPDFListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
                uploadPDFS =  new ArrayList<>();

                viewAllFiles();

                myPDFListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        uploadPDF uploadPDF = uploadPDFS.get(position);

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uploadPDF.getUrl()));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            private void viewAllFiles() {
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            uploadPDF uploadPDF = postSnapshot.getValue(uploadPDF.class);
                            uploadPDFS.add(uploadPDF);
                        }

                        String[] uploads = new String[uploadPDFS.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i<uploads.length; i++) {
                            uploads[i] = uploadPDFS.get(i).getName();

                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads){

                            @Override
                            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                                TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                                myText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                                return view;
                            }
                        };

                        myPDFListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

see and update the code for your liking;

```
//Show Progress Dialog\\
    File localFile = File.createTempFile("image", "jpg");
    yourStorageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            //Dismiss Progress Dialog\\

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //Dismiss Progress Dialog\\

        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            //calculating progress percentage
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            //displaying percentage in progress dialog
            yourProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
        }
    });
```